# How can I manually install a KDE Plasma Global Theme?

Tags: kde, plasma

Installing a global theme through the KDE store doesn't work for me, due to a bug [described here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bp2r8h/cant_install_look_and_feel_themes/). So how can I install one manually?

Comment: Which distro are you on? Maybe you can add the output of `plasmashell --version` and `kf5-config --version`. And which particular global theme is the issue?

Comment: And see the comments by "freefreeno" here about having similar difficulties: https://store.kde.org/p/1297514

Answer (score 3):

You can directly download the archive and extract it to `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/` to install it for user. If you want to install for system, then try to move it to `/usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/`